# Using Javascript libraries with CocoaScript

Tags: javascript, cocoa, plugins, libraries

I'm creating a plugin for Bohemian Coding's Sketch. They are using [CocoaScript](https://github.com/ccgus/CocoaScript) for creating plugins.

Regular coding works fine, however I wondered if it is possible to use javascript libraries with CocoaScript. Specifically I tried multiple csv-to-json libraries (such as [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/)) within my code, which failed to function.

Unfortunately I can't find almost anything on the web regarding CocoaScript, since it is not widely used. The console is also not very helpful, since Error messages are pretty basic right now.

So, long story short:

Can I use javascript libraries with CocoaScript and if yes, what are it's limitations?

Answer (score 2):

I asked the creator of CocoaScript via Twitter and this was his answer:

"You probably can't use most [libraries] without mods, it would really depend on the library."

Comment: Sure wish there was any documentation on CocoaScript whatsoever. I feel like this is a huge downfall of Sketch.